# Cordova debug in visual studio error

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, cordova

i'm developing a jquery mobile app with phonegap and visual studio for the first time and after installation i created the cordova project i wanted to test if everything works fine and it gave me an error message "`Could not find schema information for the element` " i searched the web and i got to know the problem has to do with my app manifest file.

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Deployment.Parts>
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

any help

Comment: Is your visual studio in english?

Comment: yes of course. its english